# Making $61$ by inserting arithmetical operations between $5\;5\;7\;3$. (The Australian Carriage Game (Number Puzzle))

Tags: puzzle

I know this isn't really the theme of what is going on here, but this problem is killing me, so I thought you guys could help.

The Australian Carriage Game comes from the fact that Australian trains have 2 letters and 4 numbers making up a carriage code. The rules are using these 4 numbers in their exact order, you must make the given number (In this case, 61) by inserting mathematical signs and symbols in between each character. An example of such a solution would be: (Keep in mind you normally aim for 10, but I was challenged to make 61)

$$3 3 3 6 \quad\to\quad 3/3 + 3 + 6 = 10$$

A list below shows the acceptable functions:

1. Addition
2. Subtraction
3. Division
4. Multiplication
5. Factorials
6. Bracket use
7. Exponentials and roots ONLY if the numbers are involved (i.e. you
   can't say $5^0$ unless $5$ and $0$ were next to each other in that order)
8. Permutations and combinations (eg, if $6$ and $5$ were next to each other, in that order, you could use $6 \choose 5$).
9. Concatenation (eg, if $6$ and $7$ were next to each other, you can combine them to
   make $67$)

*Unacceptable* functions include

1. Floor and ceiling functions
2. Use of $e$
3. Double and triple (and so on) factorials, and derangements (subfactorials)

If you want to present any other functions that could be used, ask me and I'll confirm.

> The specific problem is to make $61$ from only the numbers $5\;5\;7\;3$.
>
> Remember: All four numbers must be used, in the order given.
>
> **Note:** I have no reason to believe that there is actually a solution.

I can make $60$ (as $5(5 + 7!/((3!)!))$) and $62$ (in some simple way I forgot, sorry), but I can't get to $61$.

Can anyone help me out?

EDIT: Credit for Michael Albanese's solution of $5!! + 5!! + 7!!! + 3$, using the [double and triple "multifactorial"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html) (eg, $5!!=5\cdot (5-2)\cdot (5-4)=15$ and $7!!!=7\cdot (7-3)\cdot (7-6)=28$). I don't consider this a viable solution and the question is still open, but it was a route I hadn't considered, and definitely works!

Thanks!

Comment: Where did the 2, 9 and the order come from? The aim is to use only numbers 5 5 7 3 in that exact order, and using all 4 numbers. Thanks!

Comment: Would you accept $5!! + 5!! + 7!!! + 3 = 61$?

Comment: Does that have 61 as the last digits? If so, the full number has to be equal to 61, so it doesn't work. Thanks for the attempt though!

Comment: No, the number is equal to 61. I am using the double and triple factorial, not repeated factorials.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't consider the possibility of double and triple factorials. Awesome soln by the way! I don't feel this really counts, but I'll still credit the soln in the question. Thanks again!

Comment: @PedroHablespanyos: Do you have reason to believe that there is a solution?

Comment: You can avoid triple factorial and just use single and double factorial:
$5!!+5-7+(3!)!!=15+5-7+48=61$

Comment: I don't have any reason to believe that there may be a solution no.

Comment: if there was a final 2 we'd have $(5+5)\cdot 7-3^2$

Answer (score 1):

If subfactorial !n is allowed (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html), you can do it via

> $ 55+7-(!(!3))=61 $